# how to auth the JWT in android

Tags: android, jwt, json-web-token

Im really new in `android`. I have the `HTTP` Headers:

```
"Authorization": "JWTeyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6MjcsImVtYWlsIjoiZ2xvcmlhNjhAaG90bWFpbC5jb20iLCJpYXQiOjE1MDMwOTg3MzEsImV4cCI6MTUwMzcwMzUzMX0.zm7snOtUVhgvxqsEWZOsIxa1jiFRRvGZbW0JFNSnwKk"
```

something like the above saved in message1

The question is how to auth these values in my code for having the result that i need

I leave the code that i have been testing

```
public class fragmenttab_datospersonales extends Fragment {


    TextView txtprueba, txtid;
     Button btnprueba;
    String url = "http://10.8.0.1:8080/api/jugador/";
    RequestQueue requestQueue;

    String url1 = VariablesGlobales.urlid;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lyt_fragmenttab_datospersonales, container, false);

        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

        txtprueba = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtprueba);
        txtid = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtid);
        btnprueba = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnprueba);
        btnprueba.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                txtprueba.setText("holaaaaaaaaaaaaa");

                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),url2,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                obtnerdatosjason();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    private void obtnerdatosjason()  {

        String url2 = url+url1;
      //HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url2);
        String message1 = VariablesGlobales.message;

       //get.addHeader("Authorization", "Token token=\"" + message1.toString() + "\"");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message1.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //get.addHeader("Authorization", message1);

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,null, url2, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                try {
                    txtid.setText(response.getString("nombres"));
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),response.getString("nombres"),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            }
        });requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    }
}
```